# PHPMYADMIN resize editor height size

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, phpmyadmin

In below screenshot of phpmyadmin, you can see limited editor size of phpmyadmin.
The height is very small and we have problem coding from this editor.
How to resize this editor?

**Standard Editor:**

[image]

**INLINE editor:**

[image]

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? In the current version (4.2.6), you have a resize control in the bottom right corner of this window.

Comment: @MarcDelisle my phpmyadmin is 4.2.6 and i do not see any control in bottom right

Comment: please describe your browser.

Comment: @MarcDelisle , Firefox and other problem for that is don't have date time picker in input tags

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problems in Firefox (which Firefox version are you using?); did you try after disabling all of your Firefox extensions? Also, did you try with another browser?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I downloaded [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome ([GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox) and created my own script to overwrite the styles.

You could do the same, just open the interface, add a new script and paste this in:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         phpMyAdmin SQL editor height fix
// @namespace    http://josephwebber.ca/
// @version      1.1
// @description  Changes the SQL editors' height
// @author       Joseph Webber
// @match        phpMyAdmin
// @include      */phpMyAdmin/*
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

// 1.0    
//GM_addStyle(".CodeMirror { min-height: 49px !important } .CodeMirror, #inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror, .CodeMirror-wrap .CodeMirror-scroll { height: auto !important; }");

// 1.1
GM_addStyle(".CodeMirror { min-height: 49px !important } .CodeMirror, #inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror, .CodeMirror-wrap .CodeMirror-scroll { height: auto !important; } .sql { max-height: initial !important; }");
```

This way even if phpMyAdmin's files are updated, your changes won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this, one works for that session, but once you refresh the page or re-open your browser you will have to redo the steps.

Temporary solution:

In Google Chrome / your favourite web browser, right click the Inline Editor and choose Inspect Element.

Find `<div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default CodeMirror-wrap">` and under Styles change:

```
#inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror {
  height: 6em;
}
```

to something larger, say, `60em;`.

The permanent solution would be to edit `phpmyadmin.css` and change that line. With the version I'm running it's ~line 3885.

This makes the box bigger, but the lines of text it allows before it puts a scrollbar in that area is the same 5 - 10 you get. So we need one more change.

```
<div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1" style="height: 75px;">
```

is the next offending line. In the Chrome Inspector change `height: 75px;` to `height: 750px;`.

Since this is done with the style attribute and not CSS I think you're out of luck for making this a permanent fix unless you edit the `sql.php` file and find where it's making that attribute and rewrite it.

Not sure why they don't just add a thing in the bottom right so you can increase the size of the box, it drives me nuts too.

EDIT: If you ever write a GreaseMonkey script or a Google Chrome Extension or something that fixes this for me - let me know!

Comment: thanks to your reply.i can find this setting into phpmyadmin `Features`,but this Features do not have any setting for inline editor size.

Comment: I made a TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey script for this problem, check out my answer.

Comment: @JosephWebber Thanks Joseph, +1'd your answer, it works as expected.

Comment: @RyanKempt cPanel updated their phpMyAdmin which added a max-height to the window. All you have to do is add `.sql { max-height: initial !important }` to my answer to make it work again (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the height of **Inline Edit Box** pls flow below step.

for phpmyadmin version: **4.5.1**. Theme: **pmahomme**

path of my phpmyadmin theme folder: **C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\themes\pmahomme\css**

Edit : **codemirror.css.php**

From : `#inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror {
    height: <?php echo ceil($GLOBALS['cfg']['TextareaRows'] * 0.4); ?>em;
}`

To:`#inline_editor_outer .CodeMirror {
    height: <?php echo ceil($GLOBALS['cfg']['TextareaRows'] * **2**); ?>em **!important**;
}`

then do **Ctrl+f5** - to refresh the phpmyadmin tab.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.inc.php file, which you find either within your phpmyadmin folder, if you installed it manually or in case you installed it under Ubuntu as a package unter /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

you add near the bottom the following line

```
$cfg['TextareaRows'] = 8; // number of rows for the sql editor textarea
```

above the end of the file

```
/* Support additional configurations */
foreach (glob('/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/*.php') as $filename)
{
    include($filename);
}
```

Then save and reload your phpmyadmin page. The changes take effect immediately.

in this file you can set a lot of other configuration, too.